# Finitely generated section ring of Mori dream spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties, minimal-model-program

**Set-up:** We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a Mori dream space. Define, following Hu-Keel, the Cox ring of $X$ as the multisection ring
$$\text{Cox}(X)=\bigoplus_{(m_1\ldots,m_k)\in \mathbb{N}^k} \text{H}^0(X,m_1L_1+\ldots+m_kL_k)$$
for $L_1,\ldots,L_k$ a collection of line bundles of $X$ which is a basis of $\text{Pic}(X)_{\mathbb{Q}} $ such that $ \overline{\text{Eff}(X)}\subset \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Q}_+L_i$.

Since $X$ is a Mori dream space, it is a well-known result that $\text{Cox}(X)$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

**Question:** Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$. Is it true that the section ring $R(X;L)$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra?

So far, I'm aware that this is the case for toric varieties (see Gonzalez-Laface, Remark 4.1). Unfortunately, their strategy seems to rely on the combinatorial properties of toric divisors. Any hekp would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a normal variety and $\Gamma\subset WDiv(X)$ a semigroup of Weil divisors on $X$. Define
$$
R(X,\Gamma) = \bigoplus_{D\in\Gamma}H^{0}(X,D).
$$
In particular, when $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow Cl(X)$ is an isomorphism you get the Cox ring, and when $\Gamma$ is the group generated by a divisor $D$ you get the multisection ring of $D$.

If $X$ is a Mori dream spaces and $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated group then $R(X,\Gamma)$ is finitely generated. You can find a proof in Lemma 2.7 of "Mori dream spaces and blow-ups" by Ana-Maria Castravet:

https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10108767